# Alias hostname for localhost

Tags: localhost, alias, hostname

Assuming that a local Python-Script is running a webserver.

Is there any way to set an alias, so that `http://localwebapp/` equals `http://localhost:1234/`?

Edit: Or at least `http://localwebapp:1234/` equals `http://localhost:1234/`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When the browser sees `http://localwebapp/` it first tries to determine the IP address of `localwebapp`. If this succeeds, the browser establishes a TCP connection with that host, using a specific port (which is 80 for HTTP, unless some other port is mentioned in the URL).

Resolving `localwebapp` to an IP address does not take port information into account, so pointing `http://localwebapp/` to `http://localhost:1234/` can only be done by means of a HTTP redirection.

---

To make `http://localwebapp:1234/` the same as `http://localhost:1234/`, edit the `hosts` file of your operating system by adding the line

```
127.0.0.1 localwebapp
```

The location of the `hosts` file depends on the operating system:

- For ***UNIX-like*** operating systems, it's usually `/etc/hosts`.
- For ***Windows***, it's usually: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: For Windows, the hosts file is usually: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: how can one make a HTTP redirection on pure localhost (no webserver running)?

Answer (score 19):

the second option (just alias the hostname without the port information) is possible by adding localwebapp to your hostsfile ( `/etc/hosts` in *NIX, `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in windows)

adding

```
127.0.0.1 localwebapp
```

should do the trick
(assuming your local python script does not do virtual hosting and serves the same content for all domains requested)

Answer (score 9):

You can make `localwebapp` as alias for `localhost` in `/etc/hosts`. Then you can run a webserver (Apache and friends) to detect that hostname.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localwebapp

    # redirect elsewhere
    Redirect localhost:1234

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What to do, if I want to redirect from myfolder.com to localhost/myfolder (just on my private PC). I tried to set VirtualHost with the same way, but it did'nt work for me. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to this path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. Open the file hosts as administrator and change the localhost configuration. For example in my case I want to show app.com instead of localhost. I just add the app.com in front of 127.0.0.1 localhost and ::1.
Host File changes
127.0.0.1      localhost  app.com
::1            localhost  app.com