# change laravel directory to www/cms/

Tags: php, laravel

Currently my directory is var/www/
but i have other projects in this directory .for example:
**var/www/wordpress/**

laravel tell me :
**Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**

how can change laravel directory to var/www/cms ?
does work another project?
how can do that?

Comment: you need to create your project folder `/var/www/cms` --  Then build your laravel project **inside** the `cms` directory -- IE `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name`.. Then you need to point your web server to that directory for the web address to be "live"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented earlier .. But I think to make the comment more clear I am going to go ahead and answer this:

First what you need to do is `cd` into `/var/www/cms`

Next you need to create your `Laravel` application.  While in the `cms` directory, issue your Laravel creation command IE `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name`.  Once it is finished .. You should have a directory *in* the `cms` directory named whatever you named your `Laravel` Project IE `var/www/cms/your-project-name`.

You then need to point your hosts file (whether Nginx or Apache) to the directory `var/www/cms/your-project-name` for whatever domain.

I hope this was simplified enough for you, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Laravel Valet could be one of the Solution.
2. You could create seperate Host for your Specific Application at Localhost.
   Explained here : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425086/alias-hostname-for-localhost`
3. You could Create new Directory and run your Laravel Project there too.