# Cannot set an IP address on Express JS app

Tags: javascript, express

Trying to test an endpoint in express But keep getting 404 error.

```js
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
//var http = require('http').Server(app)
app.get('/', function(req,res){

        res.send('ok from end point')
})
var port = process.env.PORT|| 8080
var localhost = 'someLocalHost.med.gov'
console.log({'localhost':localhost,
                'post':port})
//
app.listen(port,localhost,function(err){

        if (err){
                console.log('err')
        }
        else {
                console.log('Listening')
        }
})
```

When I go to 
http://someLocalHost.med.gov:8080/ 
I get a 404 error

Comment: Look up the `||` operator.  You are doing `process.env.PORT` **OR** `8080`.  In other words, if `process.env.PORT` is set, that's the value that will be used, and `8080` will only be used if the former is not set.

Comment: Perhaps you need to read about how DNS works.  Your server runs at an IP address and a client connects to an IP address.  It is DNS that allows a client to lookup `somehost.med.gov` and find out the IP address that it should use to connect with.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost refers to `127.0.0.1`. You can't just launch a server on any address that you want. If you're wanting to override `localhost` you can look into modifying your [`HOSTS` file locally to setup an alias for `localhost`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425086/alias-hostname-for-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up http:// IP_ADDRESS:8080 and that took care of it.