# How to set website adress as URL instead of IP adress?

Tags: web, url, hosting

I started learning some website designing and I wonder how can I make my site adress look f. ex. like *ender.com* instead of IP address and port. I'm doing everything on my own computer, so I would really appreciate way, which will allow me to host a website on it. I'm a beginner, so I'd like to know if I'm even capable of doing this.

Comment: _"I'm doing everything on my own computer"_ - If you are only interested in being able to access your website from your own computer, you can create an alias for `localhost`. See [Alias hostname for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19425086/12567365). How exactly you do this will depend on what OS you are using. If you want your site to be visible on the public internet, then you need to (buy and) register a domain name, as the first step. But at that point I would say, use a hosting service, not your own PC.

Answer (score 0):

You need a domain name in which you're gonna host your website, in your case its `ender.com`, as you run your website from your own pc it shows your localhost and port instead of `ender.com` as you don't own that domain. Only way to show `ender.com` is that you buy that domain and host the website with that purchased domain.

Refer this for more info [https://blog.resellerclub.com/how-to-host-a-domain-website-on-your-own/#:~:text=%20A%20few%20steps%20on%20how%20to%20host,may%20have%20issues%20here%20based%20on...%20More%20](https://blog.resellerclub.com/how-to-host-a-domain-website-on-your-own/#:%7E:text=%20A%20few%20steps%20on%20how%20to%20host,may%20have%20issues%20here%20based%20on...%20More%20)